# Azure Logic App condition - Property contains in object within an array

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

value is an array with objects that have a property called skuPartNumber (string). How do I make a condition that is true when there are any objects where the skuPartNumber is equal to "X" in the array.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can use `contains` function to implement it easily. As your screenshot shows, but need to make some changes.

First, you need to know the expression of `value`. It seems the `value` comes from "**Parse JSON**" in your logic app. So the expression of `value` should be like `body('Parse_JSON')?['value']`. Then use a `string()` function to convert it to string, then judge if it contains `"skuPartNumber":"x"`.

[image]

The expression is `string(body('Parse_JSON')?['value'])`.

I think the solution above is easy enough, but if you don't want to think of it as a string to judge if it contains `"skuPartNumber":"x"`. You can also loop the `value` array, get each item and judge if the field `skuPartNumber` equals to `x`. Do it like below screenshot:

[image]

After the "**For each**" loop, use a "**If**" condition to judge if the variable `result` equals `true` or `false`.